# Should a method call to get data be before a foreach loop?

Tags: c#, performance, foreach

I currently have a snippet of code that will act upon every user found in `Active Directory` and as I was looking at it I started to wonder if it is better to have the method call done before the `foreach` loop or if it is ok the way it is. I have tested using `principalSearcher.FindAll())` both inside and out of the loop and can't notice a difference but then there is not really a large enough data set to see one, so I am wondering about this more from a best practice situation.

```
foreach (var user in principalSearcher.FindAll())
{
    var employeeID = db.Employees
                        .Where(employee => employee.ADUserName == user.SamAccountName && employee.EndDate == null)
                        .Select(employee => employee.ID)
                        .FirstOrDefault();

    if (employeeID > 0)
    {
        var updatedEmployee = db.Employees.Find(employeeID);
        updatedEmployee.EndDate = DateTime.Today;
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Note: `principalSearcher` is of type `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalSearcher`

Comment: It won't matter performance-wise - the only difference will be whether the results are available outside of the `foreach` scope or not.  The clal will only be made once in either case.

Comment: Why at all you think there can be difference?

Comment: @Evk Because I don't know how a foreach loop gets compiled down and if it would end up doing multiple calls to AD or not. I figured it would not but I thought it would be nice to know 100%.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `foreach` will get compiled to (roughly)

```
//begin decomposition of foreach (var user in principalSearcher.FindAll())

var temp = principalSearcher.FindAll();
var enum = temp.GetEnumerator();
while(enum.MoveNext())
{
    var user = enum.Current;
    // body of foreach block
}
// end decomposition
```

versus

```
// local variable outside of foreach
var allPrincipals = principalSearcher.FindAll();


//begin decomposition of foreach (var user in allPrincipals)
var enum = allPrincipals.GetEnumerator();
while(enum.MoveNext())
{
    var user = enum.Current;
    // body of foreach block
}
// end decomposition
```

So whether you declare a variable outside of the `foreach` and use it or not makes no practical difference.

*Note that  I do not include other artifacts like `try/finally` or casting/boxing since they are not germane to the question.

Comment: Thanks for this break down, not only does it answer my question it enlightens me on how the loop is complied so I can understand the underling works as well.

Comment: I have learned a lot.